# Formula Field Image in FSL Mobile App

Tags: field-service-lightning

I have a custom formula field that outputs an IMAGE based on a boolean, it's working fine both for desktop and the mobile app but doesn't render anything on Field Service mobile app is it a limitation?
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_limits.htm&type=5 here it's said that formulas are not supported but I have more formulas showing on the app the only difference between those and the non working one is the IMAGE. Any ideas of what could be the issue?

ps: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_data_types.htm&type=5 Even though the first links shows formulas are not supported this one says otherwise